# Data appears in console but does not render when I use a V-for Loop( Vuex and GraphQl)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, vuex, vue-apollo

I currently have my project set up in GraphQL and Vuex in my vue JS project, I was able to call my data from my Django backend but, I get errors when I try to render the data using a V-for Loop in Vue  Js. The element just disappears.

Here is my GraphQL setup.

```
// Apollo client Setup

import Vue from 'vue'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'

// import { USER_ID, AUTH_TOKEN } from './constants/settings'



const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: token ? `JWT ${token}` : null
    }
  })

  return forward(operation)
})


// HTTP connection to the API
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql',
})

// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache()



// Create the apollo client
export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
 
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true,
})


const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})

Vue.use(VueApollo)

export default apolloProvider
```

Here is the setup in my Vuex store

```
import { apolloClient } from '../../apollo'
import {PORTFOLIO_LIST} from '../../graph/queries.js'


const state =  {

    portfolios:[],
    portfolio:'',

};


const getters = {

    allPortfolios:(state) => state.portfolios,

};


const mutations = {

    SET_PORTFOLIOS(state, portfolios){

        state.portfolios = portfolios
    },

    SET_PORTFOLIO(state, portfolio){

        state.portfolio = portfolio
    }

};

const actions = {

 // The Portfolio list API 

async portfolioList({commit}){

    try{


        const response = await apolloClient.query({query: PORTFOLIO_LIST})
        const portfolios = JSON.stringify(response.data.portfolios)
        commit('SET_PORTFOLIOS', portfolios)

        console.log(portfolios)

    }
    catch(e){

        console.log(e)
    }

},

// The Portfolio Detail API

async portfolioDetail({commit}, ){

    try{

        const response  =  await apolloClient.query()
        const portfolio = JSON.stringify(response.data)
        console.log(portfolio)
        commit ('SET_PORTFOLIO', portfolio)
    }
    catch(e){

        console.log(e)
    }
},

//The Portfolio Create API

// async portfolioCreate({commit}, ...portfolioDetail){


// },

// The Portfolio Delete API

// async portfolioDelete({commit}){


// },

};


export default {

    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
}
```

And finally here is where I call my Vue Js for loop

```
<template>
    
    <div class="px-6 lg:px-32 h-screen">

        <section v-for ="portfolio in portfolios" :key="portfolio.id" class="mt-24 grid lg:grid-cols-3" >


        <!--    The card section -->
        
            <div>
                {{portfolio.about}}
            </div>

        <!-- End of the card section -->
            

        
            


        </section>
        

    </div>


</template>


<script>

import { mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {


computed:{

    ...mapState(['portfolios']),
},

created(){
        

    this.$store.dispatch('portfolioList');

    
    }

}
    


</script>
```

I get a response in Vue JS dev tools, but it does not iterate in my Vue js code

When I open my console, The section where I iterated over, just disappears

Comment: Hi, What is `item.id` in `key`? It should be `portfolio.id` or any other unique value from the `portfolio`.

Comment: I made it portfolio.id but still did not work. what happens when I open my console is that the element there just disappears